# DataTable.Clear() method affect detached row

Tags: c#, ado.net, strongly-typed-dataset

I'm trying to do something like this to create copy of a typed datarow:

```
var desRow = dataTable.NewRow();
var sourceRow = dataTable.Rows[rowNum];
desRow.ItemArray = sourceRow.ItemArray.Clone() as object[];
```

But when I call `dataTable.Clear()` method it clears all fields in desRow. How to create a deep copy of a `DataRow`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code when you create your new row you create with that row a reference to the dataTable and that is why it clears all fields.

You can work with a data table clone, that way you will have a deep copy.

```
DataTable dt = ...
DataTable cloneDt = dt.Clone();

DataRow row = cloneDt.Rows[number];

dt.Rows.Clear();
dt.Rows.Add(row);
```

This way you will have your original data table with only the selected row.